Why is "on" the optimal preposition in "tilt on its axis"?
Could someone explain why on (the first on) is used in this case?


The answer comes from Earth's slight tilt on its axis, about 23.4 degrees on average.

Source: What causes the seasons?

Which preposition would you prefer? Also, if it's not too much trouble, you should quote the sentence in your question so people using screen reader software can read it and so it can be searched for and cut-and-pasted. The dictionary will tell you that on can be used to refer to a support (on a nail, on a flagpole, etc), and the axis can be viewed as the support or fixed point around which the earth turns.

Very simple; The Earth has an axis, and it tilts on it.

I've heard people say that Earth spins on an axis and that the axis is tilted, but I don't think I've ever heard anyone say Earth has a tilt on its axis. I wonder if the author here accidentally blended the two statements together.

Prepositions are one of those areas of any language where you should rarely ever ask ‘why’, because the simple answer will always be ‘because that’s how we do it’ and the complicated answer will either involve complex psycholinguistics or be wholly unsatisfying.

It's the Earth's axis itself that's tilted (with respect to the ecliptic, or a line normal to the ecliptic), not the Earth relative to anything. The entire sentence is awkward, no matter what preposition you use. I'd write something like "The answer comes from the tilt of the Earth's axis, ...".

the author should have used the word of

It's often fairly meaningless to ask why English favours one preposition over others. Particularly in a context like this, where the usage chart...

...shows significant change over time. Until a decade or two ago, it was more common to refer to the tilt of its axis (but off, to, in, and possibly others are all perfectly acceptable, albeit less common).
I'd guess the switch to on is connected to the thousands of exoplanets that have been discovered recently, but I certainly can't explain why that should be so. Perhaps today's astrophysicists in general have different language preferences to an earlier generation of earth-bound geographers!

It's the earth's tilt.  "The earth's slight tilt in its axis" isn't quite grammatical.  We could say "owing to the slight tilt in the earth's axis" but not "The earth's slight tilt in its axis".

"Isn't quite grammatical"? Nonsense! Youi're just not so used to it, but there are hundreds of published written instances on tilt in its axis.

Do you understand "The earth's slight tilt in its axis" to be the equivalent in meaning of "the slight tilt of the earth's axis"?  "The song's atonality in its bridge" and "The atonality of the song's bridge".  Do they have the same meaning, as you parse those phrases?

I'm not disputing "tilt in its axis" but the use and position of the saxon possessive in those constructions  vs the periphrastic prepositional phrase.

It's fortunate that the earth is not tilted off its axis, as that would mean the axis is no longer going through the poles. Most the quotes in your link are from apocalyptic fiction.

I'd say that "tilt off its axis", while grammatically correct, has a very different meaning from the others here. || Separately, the rise in popularity of "on" appears to have begun well before the first confirmation that exoplanets exist (1992) and even the first unconfirmed detection of one (1988); they were not really a topic in the public mind until well after this, so I question whether there's any relation.

@FumbleFingers — if we are being technical “in its axis” is grammatically correct, as are “under”, “across”, “behind”, and any other preposition, regardless of how little sense it made.  The grammar “[preposition] [possessive pronoun] [noun]” is unquestionable, regardless of the words chosen.  “Tilt giraffe its axis” would be ungrammatical.  “Tilt unwrap its axis”, “Tilt its its axis”,  "Tilt smiling its axis” would all be ungrammatical.  See Chomsky.

In a late 14th century translation into Middle English from the Latin of De Proprietatibus Rerum by Bartholomew the Englishman,  a scholar in the 12th century in Paris who is thought to have studied at Oxford, we find  (spelling modernized)

Heaven is movable... and the moving thereof is round about the middle upon a line that is called axis, that stands between two stars that are called poles, that are the most south star and the most north star.

We find also "rotate about an axis", but when the concept involves the fixity of the axis and the idea that the heavens are somehow mounted on or attached to the axis, then "on" and "upon" are the natural choices based on how that preposition was (and is) used in analogous circumstances (such as meat turning on a spit, a wheel turning on an axle).
The same prepositions, on and about, are attested in the late 15th century with the verb turn, the former, again, when the core idea is the fixity of the axis and the latter when rotating movement is the focus.

For full evenly [i.e. in perfect alignment, exactly where it should be] stands [the star] in that one end of that  axle-tree that all the world turns on.

So these prepositions have been used with verbs related to axially spinning things, like an axle or an axis,  for  well over 600 years.
P.S.  In the question it is "the earth's ... tilt". The answer provided by FumbleFingers doesn't include the possessive "earth's" but focuses on the prepositions that are used when attributing a tilt to "its" axis:

tilt in its axis
tilt of its axis
tilt to its axis

These constructions strike my ear as a bit, or as more than a bit, "off" because of the combination of the possessive "earth's" and the prepositional phrase that includes "its":

The earth's tilt in its axis
The earth's tilt of its axis
The earth's tilt to its axis.

I'm focusing on the language, not on the geophysics.

The "analogous circumstances" explanation makes the most sense to me.  It's common for textbooks to illustrate Earth's axis as if it were a physical rod going through the planet.  If we say that a popsicle is on a stick, or a piece of steak is on a kabob skewer, then it's only natural to say that our planet is on an axis, even if the axis is not actually a physical rod.

An axis is an imaginary line that runs through a celestial body.
A celestial body is a spheroid.
A line that runs through a spheroid can run through it at an angle, i.e. it is tilted. (not vertical but at an angle).
When something is at an angle like this, we say: it is tilted on an axis.
We also says: things are mounted on a axis.
